# как в javaScript вызвать рандомно функцию?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть 4-ре функции red(),yellow(),green(),blue(); мне надо вызвать одну из них рандомно.
пробовал сделать через массив ничего не получилось((

```
var arrFunc=["red()","yellow()","green()","blue()"];
function randFunc() {
        return arrFunc[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrFunc.length)];
    }
  var randF=randFunc();   
    setTimeout(function() {
   randF.replace(/"/g);
        }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const red = () => {
  console.log('red');
}

const yellow = () => {
  console.log('yellow');
}

const green = () => {
  console.log('green');
}

const blue = () => {
  console.log('blue');
}

const arrFunc = [red, yellow, green, blue];
randFunc = () => {
  arrFunc[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrFunc.length)]();
}

setInterval(randFunc,1000);
```

Comment: Боже, ваши `() => {...}` и `const` режут мне глаза :)

Comment: еще вопрос как в именно в сет-интервал на консоли увидеть какая ф-я запускается

Answer (score 4):

Вы близки к цели, но всё проще:

```
var arrFunc=["red", "yellow", "green", "blue"];
function randFunc() {
  window[arrFunc[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrFunc.length)]]();
}
setTimeout(randFunc, 1000);
```

Comment: Это слишком просто. Что делать если все же у нас массив не функций, а их имен строковых?

Comment: а как вы запишите в масив [red, yellow, green, blue] если ето строки

Comment: @НазарКалитюк в принципе это не сильно усложняет, т.к. к любой переменной можно обратится по "индексу" у родительсткого объекта: `window[arrFunc[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrFunc.length)]]();`

Comment: @xlabuchik ну есть надо чтобы прям строки были, то см. подправленный код.

Comment: @xlabuchik наверное ошибка где-то в коде. Такое часто бывает когда упрощенный пример переносится в более сложный код. Проверьте на более простом примере что код работает так как вы ожидаете. Если работает, то разбрайтесь со сложным примером, если не работает, то значит надо искать ошибку тут.

Comment: Если функция, например *red*, находиться не в глобальной области видимости(window), то работать не будет. setTimeout умеет выполнять и функции, заданный в виде строки. Т.е. можно сделать так `return arrFunc[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrFunc.length)]`.